# Why React Redux context.store is undefined in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to access store from child components, but its always undefined, and due to this I have to pass the properties to child component.

This is the main app starting point:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <SignUpContainer />
  </Provider>,
  container
);
```

Where `SignUpContainer` is:

```
const SignUpContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SignUpComponent);
```

Where `SignUpComponent` is a normal react component:

```
export default class SignUpComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"sign-up-component " + this.context.store.theme}>
        // Form
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I am always getting `context.store` as `undefined`. 
Is there anything wrong to define the context.

I am looking to access the store details implicitly in child component (and children in the sub levels) without  explicitly passing them.

React version is: `16.8.6`.

Comment: show us your ```mapStateToProps``` object

Comment: Its the initial state with a property of theme. `{theme: 'dark', // all other state }`

Comment: @PiccazaDe : just for the record, `mapStateToProps` is a ***function** that is expected to return an object*, not *an object* and you don't really need to map your entire state to the properties of a given component but only those, that are required (you may refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59263105/11299053) for example)

Comment: Have you solved your problem or still looking for the answer? If former is the case, which solution did you end up with?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you will pass the desired props to the component when you connect to the store through `mapStateToProps` and then you access as regular props in your component.

so for example

```
// State of type StoreType
const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreType) => ({
  theme: state.theme
});

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className={"button " + this.props.theme}>
        Button
      </button>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
      mapStateToProps
    )(Button);
```

Comment: In that case if the `SignUpComponent` more children do we have to explicitly pass props to its child component also. I am not sure about the working of `context` but seen some docs and examples which say how we can access the information from context without passing them down implicitly. I think that's what PO is looking for.

Comment: @Dipak no, you connect each child to the store (the child that you need the props from the store)

Comment: @Nicholas, I am looking to access the store details implicitly in child component (and children in the sub levels) without  explicitly passing them.

PS: I will update this in question.

Comment: sorry. I made a small mistake in my code. I updated. 
You have to connect your child to the store. Thats what redux is made for to have a global state and avoid passing the props to the child components manually.  You connect the component to the store and get the props.

Comment: @Nicholas Can you update your answer if there is a children for `SingUpComponent` lets say `Button` and how to access the theme without passing that implicitly as props.

Comment: @PiccazaDe ofcourse. So its basically the same. You connect the button to the store and get the theme. This will automatically pass the theme props to the Button Component. There is no other way around. You have to connect your component to the store and get the param

Comment: I am still not able to get the code flow.

1. `mapStateToProps` for connecting `Button` component will come form where? 
2. If the child component is in different file, at what point I should do `connect` for `Button` component?

Comment: ```mapStateToProps``` its just an object that you pass as the first argument to the ```connect()```. You declare it in the ```Button.jsx``` file. 

You connect to the store in ```Button``` component. In your file ```Button.jsx or Button.tsx``` you import ```connect``` from redux. And you wrap your component as a ```HOC``` when you export it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's something wrong in the way you try to pass required part of the state to your component, since you should refer to component prop, which state variable `theme` is mapped onto with `mapStateToProps()`, rather than `this.context.store.theme`.

You may find below the distilled example of how that should be done, hope that gives you the clue:

```js
//dependencies
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { createStore } = Redux,
      { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux
      
//store initialization
const defaultState = {
        someProp: 'propValue',
        anotherProp: 'justAnotherValue',
        theme: 'someTheme'
      },
      appReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => state,
      store = createStore(appReducer)
//custom component
const MyComponent = ({componentTheme}) => (
  <div>
    the theme is {componentTheme}
  </div>
)
//custom component wrapper
const mapStateToProps = ({theme}) => ({componentTheme: theme}),
      MyContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
//provider wrapper
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MyContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.4/redux.min.js"></script><script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.1/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I am also reading through this answer, don't know why it got down voted. It would be better if get some reason for the -1